# checkbox form in a session doesn't work properly

Tags: php, function, session, input

I'm trying to write the code for an online form:

On page 1 there are just some demographic questions. It's on that first page I start a session. When they submit their answers they get redirected to page 2 where I place some statements on which they can select their level of agreement.
 - In case they want to go back their answers on the previous page are remembered thanks to the session.
 - Ultimatly their answers will be transferred to a database (haven't written that yet).

Problem:
1) I tried to multiply the amount of questions to 3 questions on page 2 but when I go to page 3 and return to page 2 the answers aren't remembered?

2) If I only check some of the questions (not all of them) I get 'Notice: Undefined index:' with the line the unanswered question is on. Can this be solved somehow?

**This is the code from page 2:**

```
<form action="page3.php" method="post">
<?php
    $options = array(
        'Good' => 'Good',
        'Neutral' => 'Neutral',
        'Bad' => 'Bad',
);

checkbox( 'Question_1', 'Question_1', 'How good is your health?', $options );
checkbox( 'Question_2', 'Question_2', 'How good is your math?', $options );
checkbox( 'Question_3', 'Question_3', 'How good is your knowledge of astrofysics?', $options );

?>

<?php submit('Go To Step 3 &raquo;'); ?>
</form>
```

This is the code from page 3 (where the info from page 2 is stored in the SESSION variables):

```
<?php
include_once('header.php');

// Store data from page 1 in session
if ( ! empty( $_POST ) ) {
  $_SESSION['Question_1'] = $_POST['Question_1'];
  $_SESSION['Question_2'] = $_POST['Question_2'];
  $_SESSION['Question_3'] = $_POST['Question_3'];
}

?>
```

And this is the code of the used function (from functions.php):

```
function checkbox( $name, $id, $label, $options = array() ) {?>
  <div class="form-group">
    <p><?php echo $label; ?></p>
    <?php foreach ( $options as $value => $title ) : ?>
      <label class="checkbox-inline" for="<?php echo $id; ?>">
        <input type="checkbox" required name="<?php echo $name; ?>[]" value="<?php echo $value; ?>" <?php isset($_SESSION['Question_1'],$_SESSION['Question_2'],$_SESSION['Question_3']) ? checked="checked":; ?>>
        <span class="checkbox-title"><?php echo $title; ?></span>
      </label>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The way you are trying to set the `checked` attribute makes no sense - you are checking if any of these three session variables was set in one go, so that would yield the same result for all three checkboxes all the time.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with this line:

```
    <input type="checkbox" required name="<?php echo $name; ?>[]" value="<?php echo $value; ?>" <?php isset($_SESSION['Question_1'],$_SESSION['Question_2'],$_SESSION['Question_3']) ? checked="checked":; ?>>
```

It should probably be something like:

```
    <input type="checkbox" required name="<?php echo $name; ?>[]" value="<?php echo $value; ?>" <?php isset($_SESSION[$id]) ? checked="checked":; ?>>
```

Comment: And how can I make the names 'Question_1', 'Question_2', etc (from $_SESSION ['Question_1'], etc.) become automatically the value of $id?

Comment: that should already be happening when you are setting them in your "page 3"